# AJP Connector uses in Apache and JBOSS

Tags: apache, jboss, ajp

In our project we have used ajp connector along with apache and jboss. Due to ghostcat vulnerability, we have commented ajp connector in jboss and it works fine. Later we came to know that ajp connector in jboss will handle the load balancing when used in conjunction with jvmRoute attribute. But in our project we didn't enabled "jvmRoute". The following link describes the above point.. https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/ajp.html

Please let me know the answers for below questions,

1. Difference between Apache ajp connector and jboss ajp connector.
2. Does jboss ajp connector supports load balance or not?
3. If "jvmRoute" is disabled, how the load balance is handled?

Thanks in Advance.